# Translation CNN from keras code to pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to translate the below 3layer CNN architecture from keras to pytorch. The usage of the model is to predict expression value(input_shape_val) from dna sequence(input_shape_hot). The sequence is one hot encoded. The architecture orignally meant to train the model consecutively CNN (3 layers)-FC (2 layers) with batch normalization and weight dropout were applied after all layers and max-pooling after CNN layers( [ref-paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-19921-4#Sec9), [ref-code](https://github.com/zelezniak-lab/param_pipeline/blob/random_search_with_replicates/models/THIS_CNN_NN_vals_input.py)).

```
def POC_model2(input_shape_hot,input_shape_val,DR):

    X_input1 = Input(shape = input_shape_hot)
    X_input2 = Input(shape = input_shape_val)
    # L 1: CONV
    X1 = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=10, strides=1, activation='relu')(X_input1) 
    X1 = BatchNormalization()(X1)
    X1 = Dropout(DR)(X1)
    X1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=4)(X1)
    # L 3: CONV
    X1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=10, strides=1, activation='relu')(X_input1) 
    X1 = BatchNormalization()(X1)
    X1 = Dropout(DR)(X1)
    X1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=4)(X1)
    # L 2: CONV
    X1 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=10, strides=1, activation='relu')(X_input1) 
    X1 = BatchNormalization()(X1)
    X1 = Dropout(DR)(X1)
    X1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=4)(X1)

    X1 = Flatten()(X1)

    X1 = Concatenate(axis=1)([X1,X_input2])
    # fully connected
    X = Dense(64, activation='relu')(X1)
    X = BatchNormalization()(X)
    X = Dropout(DR)(X)

    X = Dense(1)(X)

    model = Model(inputs = [X_input1,X_input2], outputs = X)

    return model
```

I tried from this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76705628/how-to-add-additional-layers-to-cnn-model-in-pytorch/76706134#76706134) :

```
from typing import List
class DNA_CNN_test2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 seq_len: int,
                 num_filters: List[int] = [32, 64,128],
                 kernel_size: int = 3,
                 p = 0.2):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        # CNN module
        self.conv_net = nn.Sequential()
        num_filters = [4] + num_filters
        for idx in range(len(num_filters) - 1):
            self.conv_net.add_module(
                f"conv_{idx}",
                nn.Conv1d(num_filters[idx], num_filters[idx + 1],
                          kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same')
            )
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"relu_{idx}", nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"batchNor_{idx}",nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters[idx + 1]))
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"dropout_{idx}",nn.Dropout(0.2))
            self.conv_net.add_module(f"MaxP_{idx}",nn.MaxPool1d(4,stride= 4))
        self.conv_net.add_module("flatten", nn.Flatten())
        self.conv_net.add_module("linear",nn.Linear(num_filters[-1]*seq_len, 1))
        
    def forward(self, xb: torch.Tensor):
        """Forward pass."""
        xb = xb.permute(0, 2, 1) 
        out = self.conv_net(xb)
        return out
```

And got error message:

```
 mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2048x1920 and 128000x1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `add_module` function for BN and dropout:

```py
self.conv_net.add_module(
  f'bn_{idx}',
  nn.BatchNorm1d(num_filters[idx + 1]),
)
self.conv_net.add_module(f'dropout_{idx}', nn.Dropout(p))
```

Comment: Thank you. now i want to add maxpool1id(4 ,stride= 4 ), however adding `self.conv_net.add_module(f"MaxP_{idx}",nn.MaxPool1d(4,stride= 4))` after droup cause `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2048x1920 and 128000x1)`

Comment: can you help with this?

Comment: `nn.MaxPool1d(4,stride= 4)` will divide the sequence length by 4. So your final dense (linear) layer that takes the flatten sequence in input should have `num_filters[-1] * seq_len // (4*len(num_filters) - 4)` units

Comment: or maybe `4**(len(num_filters) - 1)` it is more accurate